# How can I launch an invisible browser window from an android application

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, analytics, jquery-mobile

I am trying to do cookie tracking for android installs. So, when someone clicks on my link I set a cookie, than when they first open my application I load an image tag or an iframe in the phone's safari browser to pass the cookie information back to my server.

I would like it to be an invisible process, is there a way to launch an instance of the browser behind the scenes and close it? or a way to access the cookies from the android browser?

Or is there any reliable way to pass information from before the get to the android store, into the application?

Thanks!

**My solution**
my tracking solution takes the useragent and IP and creates a hash of it, than I load an invisible webview in my first activity that loads an IMG pixel, this sends back the IP and useragent which I can match up.

It's not perfect because phone carriers share quite a few IP's but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to launch an instance of the browser behind the scenes and close it?

No.

> or a way to access the cookies from the android browser?

No.

> Or is there any reliable way to pass information from before the get to the android store, into the application?

Not really. Bear in mind that with the Web-based Android Market, they do not even have to touch their device to install your app.